# can a self variable be defined inside the for loop?

Tags: python, oop

can a self variable be defined inside the for loop? it is not defined anywhere before. 
I am confused over its usage. the link from where the code is attached below.

```
def initialize_nb_dict(self):
    self.nb_dict = {}
    for label in self.labels:
        self.nb_dict[label] = defaultdict(list)
```

https://github.com/taspinar/siml/blob/master/notebooks/Naive_Bayes.ipynb

Comment: `self` is in-scope because it's an argument to the function. (If this is a class member, then it's an automatically-filled-out argument, but it's an argument either way).

Comment: Hey there... we don't understand which variable is defined inside the for loop ... but the answer is almost certainly yes (we maybe see `self.nb_dict` being defined inside the function but that is outside of the forloop

Comment: The identifier `self` has no special status. It is simply the argument to the function, this it is a local variable. That is, *it is defined*. This works for any function argument.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can.  `self` is the class instance; you can create and set attributes.  In the same way that you can do:

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.nb_dict = {}
>>> a.nb_dict[1] = 2
>>> a.nb_dict
{1: 2}
```

Within the scope of the method `initialize_nb_dict()`, `self` is the instance (like `a` above.)

There's nothing special about `self`, except that it is used by convention to refer to the instance for instance methods.  (You could even call `a` as `self`, but it would be unconventional to name an instance `self` outside of an instance method.)

---

One other minor point on terminology: you say "can a self variable be defined."  It's probably more accurate to say that an attribute of `self` is being set, rather than that `self` is being defined; it's "defined" when the instance is implicitly passed as `self` to the method.